# Hadoop: pseudo cluster, adding datanode

Tags: hadoop

am trying to install a multiple pseudo nodes for an experimental cluster. The reason is simple: I just have only one machine in my office.

Therefore, i followed this guide: and especially the answer of Matt:
http://search-hadoop.com/m/sApJY1zWgQV/

1. I created an additional folder conf2

   1.1. In hadoop-env.sh, i edited HADOOP_IDENT_STRING to ${USER}_02

   1.2. I changed the data.dir in hdfs-site.xml

   1.3. In hdfs-site.xml i changed the port of:

   - dfs.datanode.address  (default 0.0.0.0:50010)
   - dfs.datanode.ipc.address  (default 0.0.0.0:50020)
   - dfs.datanode.http.address  (default 0.0.0.0:50075)
   - dfs.datanode.https.address  (default 0.0.0.0:50475)
2. I tried the command: "./hadoop-daemons.sh --config ../conf2 start datanode"
   on my current single node hadoop system

The error is still: "localhost: datanode running as process 42855. Stop it first."

The jps command says:

```
:~/hadoop/bin$ jps 
2255 Jps 
43412 SecondaryNameNode
43853 TaskTracker
42855 DataNode
43544 JobTracker
42537 NameNode
```

Does anyone have an idea how i could trick my hadoop system to accept the additional data node now?

thanks alot

Comment: can you print the `jps` command output?

Comment: sure, here it is...

:~/hadoop/bin$ jps
2255 Jps
43412 SecondaryNameNode
43853 TaskTracker
42855 DataNode
43544 JobTracker
42537 NameNode

Comment: Did you try to do what's suggested [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-common-user/201009.mbox/%3CA3EF3F6AF24E204B812D1D24CCC8D71A03688F76@mse16be2.mse16.exchange.ms%3E)?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i found under the link and what i followed in my first post :)

Comment: Try this [script](https://gist.github.com/eliasah/6a4473120937723e8ba7) but read it first. There is some modifications that you have to do for the path